# How to use Plus tool in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, modelbuilder

I want to have the **sum** of at least 2000 raster combined to one raster layer using ModelBuilder (**[Plus tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000096000000)**). I think I'm missing something here. This model does not work.

[image: sample model builder flowchart]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the [Cell Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Cell_Statistics/009z0000007q000000/) tool. Set the **Overlay statistic** to **SUM**

Set up your model builder workspace as shown below.

**Main Model**

[image]

**Sub Model**
[image]